# Failure after uploading files with GoDady plex

Tags: php, plex

I am having hard time fixing this issue, when i upload this files on GoDaddy the phpinfo.php is working but index.php gives message "Failure", surprisingly after 6 hours same started working without any issues. I am new to php and just started one simple project for my friends website. I have uploaded my project zip file, can someone help me troubleshoot this issue.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5MAQGmHi8iZdkRtQzJzenEzMDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I reached out to goDaddy and they said the issue is with index.php, where as i am not able to understand how did it started working after 6hr if it has issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely in this line:

`mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");`

You yourself print "Failure", and the problem is with mail function. Probably godaddy hosting doesnt have installed `sendmail`. By the way, you should probably consider sending the e-mail using smtp server instead of php `mail()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try to check that. Meanwhile i just tried mail functionality from site and it does works. So it seems like mail goDaddy does have sendmail and its working as i get emails. The only issue here is site doesn't shows failure for first 1-2 hr and then works fine with no issues.

Comment: It still seems like a hosting problem, not problem with your code. Can you try other hosting to confirm, that it works somewhere else?

Comment: I tried but goDaddy just not ready to entertain that, they are not ready to accept its issue at there end. :(...

Answer (score 0):

Finally got some help from goDaddy, as per goDaddy i am using shared server and when we upload new files it doesn't take effect immediately. It may take around 10-15 min to get site up and running. I am still not convinced as phpinfo.php page is immediately available once i make changes, but looks like i have no other options. Please provide your inputs if you find anything...

Comment: GoDaddy's so shitty I'd actually believe that explanation. I'd find a new host even if they're not the cause of *this* problem.